# Cant integrate Facebook SDK Android with gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, build.gradle

I have tried all the exclusion but i always get dexindexoverflow exception.
Every time I use it, it always gives the same error.
Along with facebook, I also want to integrate digits by fabric - twitter.
Is there any way by which i can find out the dependency duplicacy for my whole project. i cant anything on gradle console.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

/** Must exclude exported support jars from dependencies, or get dex     duplicate class      error.
 *  we're
 **/
configurations {
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-     services'
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
}
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
mavenCentral()
}


android {

signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.company"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 207
    versionName "3.2.0.7"
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
}

configurations.all {
exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
// other configurations
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.7.5'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/smack.jar')
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/ActiveAndroid.jar')
compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v2.3.1.18.jar')
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
compile 'com.nhaarman.supertooltips:library:3.0.+'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:+@aar'
// compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
compile project(':parallaxviewpager')
compile project(':sliderlibrary')
// compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}


task buildAndOtaRelease(dependsOn: ['build',   'crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant: enable in your build.gradle of your main module under android the line multidexEnabled

```
android {
   ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```